# window.location.href minimising popup

Tags: javascript, jsp, popup

I'm new to jsps/javascript so please bear if Question is silly.I have goggled but could not found the answer. I have to open popup on one button click which displays the report and parent page gets refreshed. But now pop gets minimized and parent page comes to front. below is the code.

```
function bustOut()
 {     
    window.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/viewer/faces/faults/logViewer.jsf";
    var sessionId = "LR<%=session.getId()%>";
    var url="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/viewer/faces/faults/logReport_popup.jsf";
  popupwindow=window.open(url,sessionId,"height=730,width=745,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=500");
  popupwindow.focus();
}
```

when I removes window.location.href, my popup comes to front but parent page becomes blank.
I want popup window should not get minimized.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
 function bustOut()
     {     
    //no need to set href again...
        var sessionId = "LR<%=session.getId()%>";
        var url="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/viewer/faces/faults/logReport_popup.jsf";
      popupwindow=window.open(url,sessionId,"height=730,width=745,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=500");

    //reload current window after popup opens..wait for 1000ms or 2000ms..
//reload happens after 1s as per below code...
      window.setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 1000);
    }
```

Comment: After Window.location.reload(); both popup and parent are having same URL.

Comment: Looks like parent and popup window names becoming same. Do one thing: replace this line:     window.open(url,sessionId,"height=730,width=745,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=500"); with window.open(url,"_blank","height=730,width=745,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=500");